# Php ZipArchive's open/addFile method crashes with fatal error on big datasets

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-ziparchive, supervisord

We have a php (Version 5.3.10) cli application doing some heavy work on a ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine. This script can run for a long time depending on the dataset it receives. These datasets are zip files with a lot of XML, image and MS doc files.

Earlier this script used few system commands (shell, perl, java) to complete its task. We did not have problems then. Recently, we upgraded these scripts to use RabbitMQ for multiple concurrent invocations, moved from cron based working to supervisord for automatic recovery and monitoring, and also used php's core libraries and functions as much as possible to avoid shell invocations.

Now, after deploying to production, we found that the script fatally crashed on a line, where ZipArchive was used to create an archive. To be specific, only on its methods "open" and "addFile". We tested this many a times with the problematic dataset and found that this is where the real problem is.

The error thrown was "Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded". We know about php's limit on exection time and we double checked php.ini and all those settings under "/etc/php5/conf.d" folder, and everywhere we had "max_execution_time" set to 0. We also checked that the script's sapi mode was "cli" using "php_sapi_name()". ini_get("max_execution_time") also returns 0.

Even when the script is managed by supervisord, the above mode and execution limit are the same. We could not find out from where this "max_execution_time" limit of 300 seconds is being triggered.

One more thing, the script actually ran for more than 600 seconds when it crashed with this message. We also feel that, its only when ZipArchive took more than 300 seconds by itself, that this happens. But we are not sure. Also the partial zip archive it creates when this happens is between 280 MB and 290 MB. So we downloaded php source from its repository and did a quick grep to see if ZipArchive's code base had any such limits. We found none.

We are now trying to replace ZipArchive php code with shell command as a work around. We are yet to test it. I will post our findings here soon.

Had any of you faced such issues before? Is this something related to ZipArchive? Is it recommended to use ZipArchive for creating huge archives? The partial zip file it created before being crashed was between 280 MB and 290 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once when using zipArchive with files > 500 MB. In some cases it also acts up when the size is considerably smaller, but the number of files are higher. Finally I ended up creating a wrapper over the linux zip/unzip commands and used them so that in the core it is basically just doing an exec() on the OS level. Never had problems with that. Course you need a sysad to set up permissions and all, but its a stable soln.

Comment: Will try that. But the error message it throws is not helping to find the root cause. This dataset has 3 files that are close to or over 100MB in size. That is also something we are investigating on.

Comment: @PeroliSivaprakasam That seems to be coming from Apache's Timeout directive. Check your Apache config for that.

Comment: True. But it's in no way connected to apache. We are running this from command line. We have even wrote ini_set("max_execution_time", 0) at the start of this script. Still it crashed.

Comment: Sorry. set_time_out(0) does work, when included just before ZipArchive's Open method. But a robust solution is yet to be found.